# Spark create new spark session/context and pick up from failure

Tags: apache-spark, session, exception, pyspark

The Spark platform where I work is not stable and keep failing my jobs with various reason each time. The job just not die on Hadoop manager but linger as Running, so I want to kill it.

In the same python script, I would like to kill the current spark session once there is failure, create another sparkcontext/session and pick up from the last checkpoint. I do have frequent checkpoint to avoid DAG getting too long. The part where it tends to fail is a while loop, so I can afford to pick up with the current df

Any idea how I can achieve that ?

My initial thought is

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test_Terminal").config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000").getOrCreate()

flag_finish = False
flag_fail=False
while (!flag_finish) :
   if flag_fail : #kill current erroneous session 
      sc.stop()
      conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '60g'), 
      ('spark.driver.memory','30g'),('spark.executor.cores', '16'), 
      ('spark.driver.cores', '24'),('spark.cores.max', '32')])
      sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
      spark = SparkSession(sc)
      df = ...#read back from checkpoint or disk

   #process with current df or df picked up
   while .. :#this is where server tend to fail my job due after some time
       try :
          ##df processing and update
          ...
          df.checkpoint()
          df.count() #activate checkpoint 

          if complete :
              flag_finished = True
       exception Exception as e:
          flag_fail=True
          continue
```

Another question is how to explicitly read from checkpoint (which has been done by df.checkpoint())

Comment: Your initial thoughts are wrong in the end.

Comment: I think you will have to implement the checkpoint feature yourself. Maybe you can save the intermediate results and continue from them if a new execution detects its presence. At least I am not aware of any built-in feature to do it automatically.

Comment: @Selnay As bluephantom said checkpoint is not to be read back from another session, I would think of parquet or physical table. Any preferences and advantages of one over another ? How about the stopping and starting a new session ? is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: @Kenny I would go for the parquet file instead of a physical table. Mainly because it would be easier to handle multiple states (with multiple files). It would be more difficult to do that with a table, which would require multiple tables or any other more complex design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkpointing in non-Streaming is to used sever lineage. It is not designed for sharing data between different applications or different Spark Contexts.

What you would like is not possible in fact.

Comment: Good to know. I thought of it as an option. Otherwise what is you recommendation ? Parquet or writing to physical Hive table is better ?

Comment: Parquet is a format of Hive. In the old days we wrote re-startable programs, this is less the case with Spark. Spark will handle nodes failures etc. but will fail with OOM and other types of errors. Where I was we re-ran the program. In answer to your question via the comment: it is hard to answer as what are you asking? For writing intermediate files for Spark Jobs as part of Spark App? I would use AVRO or tsv, csv for intermediate files, or Parquet if a lot of AGGRegation would be needed. But what about the Spark bucketing? Handy if joining subsequently. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/restartable-jobs  My next adventure BTW.

Comment: Awesome info, thanks. My point is to create a sort of restarting mechanism myself, as you can see in the **if flag_fail**, re-spawn another session and start reading back objects needed. My script in loop tends to run for certain number of loops, but then no matter how many times it fail, if I keep restarting and pick up, eventually I'll be able to finish all loops in chunks such as 14 loops + 20 loops +12 loops. As least that's what I think. It's not the most beautiful solution of reading back every time, but that's my thought for an unstable system that keeps failing.

Comment: Well, things are what they are.